# Command line for loop logging

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, logging, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to log the results of a for loop, but only get an empty file.

What I have tried is:

```
for %%f in (mathml*.xml) do (
 "D:\ProgramFiles\formater\formater.exe" -d %%f -o %%f.pdf -p @PDF  >> result.log
)
```

and

```
for %%f in (mathml*.xml) do (
 "D:\ProgramFiles\formater\formater.exe" -d %%f -o %%f.pdf -p @PDF
)  >> result.log
```

I use the logging functionality all the time, and should be pretty strait forward and basic to use, but apparently not in a for loop..?

Does anyone know how to do this, or am I overlooking something.

Thanks!

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: Maybe that program outputs to stderr, try redirecting it with `2>&1` before `>>`

Comment: Does there appear any text on screen? (the text you want to put to the log file)

Comment: Yes, the formater produces text in cmd

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
@echo off
rem Delete log file from previous batch execution.
del result.log 2>nul
for %%I in (mathml*.xml) do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\formater\formater.exe" -d "%%~fI" -o "%%~dpnI.pdf" -p @PDF 2>&1 >>result.log
)
for %%I in (result.log) do if %%~zI == 0 del result.log
```

The log file is deleted first before writing the output of `formater.exe` to **stdout** and **stderr** to log file using [command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Instead of `D:\ProgramFiles` the value of environment variable `ProgramFiles` is used on command line in **FOR** loop.

As `mathml*.xml` could match also file names with a space in name, the references to the file names are enclosed in quotes because otherwise the arguments list for `formater.exe` could be invalid with a file name containing 1 or more spaces in name or path.

The file names are specified with full path which could be helpful on reading log file in case of an error.

The log file is deleted after loop execution finished if it is an empty file with 0 bytes.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`